# How to reverse a string without allocating memory

Tags: iphone, nsstring, reverse

I was asked this question on how to reverse a string without allocating memory. Any takers?

Comment: Are you sure the question is related to Cocoa and `NSString`?

Comment: ahhh, this is a classic Job Interview question (and you should probably add the "interview" tag to this).

Comment: I found a answer for this - And managed to implement it - I will post the answer tomorrow if no one comes up with it.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann this seems to be a nice twist on the classic though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void reverseStringBetter(char* str)
{
    int i, j;
    i=j=0;

    j=strlen(str)1;
    for (i=0; i<j; i++, j-)
    {
        str[i] ^= str[j] ;
        str[j] ^= str[i] ;
        str[i] ^= str[j] ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a typo in 'j=strlen(str)1;' ??

Comment: Also in the for loop with 'j-'

Comment: Given the other answers, it seems your answer is wrong, but you accepted it anyway!  Even if you could swap the bytes like that of an NSString, it wouldn't work.  According to http://www.objc.io/issue-9/unicode.html NSString is utf-16 encoded and indices refer to code units rather than code points (characters).

Comment: More authoritative source:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsClusters.html  "NSString lengths, character indexes, and ranges are expressed in terms of UTF-16 units, and that the term “character” in NSString method names refers to 16-bit platform-endian UTF-16 units"

Answer (score 4):

You cannot reverse an `NSString`, with or without allocating memory, because an `NSString` is immutable.

You cannot reverse an `NSMutableString` in place without allocating memory, because the only methods that `NSMutableString` provides to replace its contents require the new characters to be specified in an `NSString`, which you would have to allocate.

`CFMutableString` has the same “problem”.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with `NSString` since they are immutable and the only way is to create a new string.

Though this might not be what you are looking for, you can convert the `NSString` to a normal c-string, and edit that in-place.  You are still allocating memory, but you'll at least get half of what you want by being able to modify the string in place.

I'm not sure what your use case is for not wanting to allocate memory, or if this is simply a hypothetical.